# Make soft keyboard to fill all width of screen

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, android-softkeyboard

I am going to implement a form with `jetpack compose` and I used a `TextField` to get the user's mobile number. In order to show the keyboard I used keyboard type `NumberPassword`
inside the `TextField`:

> keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(keyboardType = KeyboardType.NumberPassword).

The problem is in widescreen devices the keyboard elements don't cover all widths of the screen and there is padding at the start and end of the keyboard. How can I remove these empty spaces?

[image: softkeyboard with spaces at the start and end]

Answer (score 1):

The keyboard's view (and its width) is controlled by the keyboard app that is installed on the device (and it will be full-screen if that app is drawing it that way).